# SQLAlchemy filter_by query failing when float used

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a model defined as follows:

```
class EnergyProfiles(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "energy_profiles"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    device_id = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=False, nullable=False)
    device_hardware = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=False, nullable=False)
    location = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=False, nullable=False)
    time = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=False, nullable=False)
    accompanied = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    wellbeing = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=False, nullable=False)
    battery = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True, unique=False, nullable=False)
```

When I add new objects via an API I would like to check that the new object (the `post_data`) does not already exist. This check was easy with

```
energy_profile_existing = EnergyProfiles.query.filter_by(**post_data).first()
```

After changing the `battery` column type, however, from `db.Integer` to `db.ARRAY(db.Float())` the previous `query.filter_by` fails with a postgres error (ignore the `user` text below, it's docker compose output logs)

```
 operator does not exist: double precision[] = numeric[]
user_1           | LINE 3: WHERE energy_profiles.battery = ARRAY[0.1,20.1]
user_1           |                                       ^
user_1           | HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

The `post_data` contains `battery` as part of the JSON object e.g.

```
{
    "device_id": "CP99",
    "device_hardware": "Pycom",
    "location": "irregular",
    "time": "daytime",
    "accompanied": false,
    "wellbeing": "ok",
    "battery": [0.11, 35.22]
}
```

Comment: Based on the error message, I am guessing that the array values in your db are stored as double precision but sqlalchemy interprets the array values from your json object as numeric. You might be able to resolve the issue by casting the array to numeric (but that will complicate your filter syntax a bit) or by converting your db array column to a numeric array.

Comment: @benvc Not SQLA, but Postgres itself, when passed an array of numeric constants (the `ARRAY[0.1, 20.1]`): "A numeric constant ...; otherwise it is taken to be type `numeric`. Constants that contain decimal points and/or exponents are always initially presumed to be type `numeric`."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @benvc and @IljaEverilä pointed out when you pass an array without any explicit casting containing non-integer numeric constants, it is assumed that they are of type `numeric`.

What you can do is [cast the array's contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064007/how-to-explicitly-cast-type-of-array-literal-in-sqlalchemy-using-postgresql) to `float` and to do that you can use the [`array([])`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.array) literal to declare the array and [`cast()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html?highlight=cast#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.cast) it to [`ARRAY(Float)`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ARRAY) using the datatype:

```
{
    "device_id": "CP99",
    "device_hardware": "Pycom",
    "location": "irregular",
    "time": "daytime",
    "accompanied": false,
    "wellbeing": "ok",
    "battery": cast(array([0.11, 35.22]), ARRAY(Float))
}
```

Comment: works a charm, thank you (and @benvc and @IljaEverilä) for the excellent explanation!